# Compilation fails on version 1.0.2p

Tags: openssl

Compilation fails with linker error although it complains with warning messages.

logs:

```
#  gcc -Wall -o server server.c -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto
server.c: In function ‘InitServerCTX’:
server.c:62:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv3_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     method = SSLv3_method();
     ^
server.c:62:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     method = SSLv3_method();
            ^
/tmp/ccYwA194.o: In function `InitServerCTX':
server.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `SSLv3_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#
```

openssl version:

```
# /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
```

Comment: Hi. Whilst by luck your error is clear, people might be downvoting you because the question lacks basic data. It is not clear: what you are trying to compile; in what distro are you.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL3 method is deprecated and is not support anymore in recent versions of OpenSSL/libssl.

Older sources that rely on OpenSSL to have SSL3 routines do not support them anymore.

Also any modern browser also dropped support to SSLv3.

As for Debian, SSLv3 support was dropped somewhere in Jessie life. Stretch has not supported it from day 0.